# Calculate the previous value in T-SQL (update)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am struggling a little, not to say, much with some SQL logic.

*Example of the Data set*

```
wid  CCVnr  Amount  Reference  Seq  Month      ColumIwant=PreviousAmount
11   15946  20      50         1    1/1/2013   NULL
12   15946  20      50         2    1/2/2013   NULL
13   15946  20      50         3    1/3/2013   NULL
14   15946  20      50         4    1/4/2013   NULL
15   15946  20      50         5    1/5/2013   NULL
16   15946  20      50         6    1/6/2013   NULL
35   15946  20      50         1    1/1/2013   NULL
36   15946  10      50         2    1/2/2013   20
37   15946  10      50         3    1/3/2013   20
38   15946  10      50         4    1/4/2013   20
39   15946  10      50         5    1/5/2013   20
40   15946  10      50         6    1/6/2013   20
88   15946  10      50         1    1/1/2013   20
89   15946  20      50         2    1/2/2013   NULL
90   15946  25      50         3    1/3/2013   10
91   15946  25      50         4    1/4/2013   10
92   15946  25      50         5    1/5/2013   10
93   15946  25      50         6    1/6/2013   10
```

The 5 first columns I have, I want to 'calculate' the last column: PreviousAmount.
The problem for me is that every time all 6 months are (re)loaded so it's not enough to look at the 'changed' value, you also have to take into account the history is there to.

 (I first had a piece of code with a CTE comparing one row to the next but like this I'm missing the history...)

Situation here is: a client has an amount he wants to pay per month he can change:
In this case the changes it from 20 to 10 to 25.

I've uploaded a CSV-file or the very dataset I'm working with here:
https://mega.co.nz/#!oZhC0RxB!CzzMx3Yr6Kx1_1N9scuNqwJnqoZDGUXte47iOPkLG-E

We using SQL Server 2008 R2.
There are 20M rows like this in the table. So maybe a cursor is not the best option(?)

Thanks a lot in advance for any help !!
L

UPDATE: 
I added a wid column because the original data set also holds a wid column.
@**Mark Bannister** The logic is to look at 'Amount' and when for a certain month the Amount is changed by the user:
    * All the next months get updated when the 'New Amount'
    * We calculate the Previous Amount which is = the Amount is was before

@**Love2Learn** also thanks for your comment. There are lots more columns but you have to know it's not easy to add more columns in the stackoverflow code block.
Therefore I also uploaded a CSV file from which you can find the link. A relevant column I do have added is the 'wid'.

Normally there should be enough info and columns to calculate this previous row.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the logic for determining which row holds the "previous" value? What is the primary key on the table?

Comment: Is the entirety of your table schema just those five columns???

Comment: Please include more information. There is no deterministic way to find the "previous row" with the data you've included in the question.

Comment: Thanks again for all comments, for more info/columns I added the CSV with the actual data! Primary key added (wid)

Answer (score 0):

You need a customer number of some sort -- to identify the groups.  Say this is `custid`:

```
select t.*,
       (select top 1 
               amount from t t2 where t2.custid = t.custid and t2.month < t.month order by t2.month
       ) as prevAmount
from t
```

Comment: Just FYI looks like `Month` is a string, so `<` won't work since it will say that `1/2013 < 6/2012`.

Comment: Sorry for the lay-out of the example...it's not perfect. But month is a datetime. I will change it to a **date** for the sake of completeness. Thanks  <br> plus: it's the French date notation, 1/6/2013 is 2013/06/01; as you know  </br>

Comment: Tried the code, not sure it is working like this ? Would it change if you use the wid ? thx